# AFNetworking 2.0 Reachability alert always showing

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 to make network calls. I am using the code below for reachability. My problem is that the "Not connected" alert always shows when I open the app. It seems like it takes a while for the app to get connected to the network and that lag is causing the alert to pop up. Is there any way to fix this? I don't want the "Not connected" alert popping up every time and confusing users.

```
 [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));

        switch (status) {
            {case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
                NSLog(@"No Internet Connection");
                UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not connected"
                                                                  message:@"You have no network connection"
                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

                [message show];
            }
                break;
            {case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                NSLog(@"WIFI");


               }
                break;
            {case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
                NSLog(@"4G");
            }
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unkown network status");

                break;
        }
    }];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]startMonitoring];

    if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable] == NO) {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not connected"
                                                          message:@"You're not connected to the internet. Please connect via WiFi or data plan"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];

        //this shows all the time - why?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `AppDelegate` in this method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. it will display message only one time.

```
internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");

        });
    };
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Internet Connection\nPlease Check The Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alrt show];
        });
    };
    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because AFNetworkReachabilityManager refreshs its status by notification.
So when you call

```
[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable]
```

after the startMonitoring immediately,the status is not get ready.

Comment: I've tried putting the alert in different places so it has a chance to get ready, but I still get the alert. What's a good practice for this?